# openui5 FileUploader not working

Tags: file-upload, sapui5

I am trying to upload a file with a simple form. I can choose a file but when I click on "upload" nothing happens.

My FileUploader.view.xml is like:

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="sap.ui.unified.sample.FileUploaderBasic.Controller"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m"
class="viewPadding">
<l:VerticalLayout>
    <u:FileUploader
        id="fileUploader"
        name="myFileUpload"
        uploadUrl="upload/"
        width="400px"
        tooltip="Upload your file to the local server"
        uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete"/>
    <Button
        text="Upload File"
        press="handleUploadPress"/>
</l:VerticalLayout>
```

My Contoller.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define(['sap/m/MessageToast','sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller'],
function(MessageToast, Controller) {
"use strict";

var ControllerController = Controller.extend("sap.ui.unified.sample.FileUploaderBasic.Controller", {
    handleUploadComplete: function(oEvent) {
        var sResponse = oEvent.getParameter("response");
        if (sResponse) {
            var sMsg = "";
            var m = /^\[(\d\d\d)\]:(.*)$/.exec(sResponse);
            if (m[1] == "200") {
                sMsg = "Return Code: " + m[1] + "\n" + m[2] + "(Upload Success)";
                oEvent.getSource().setValue("");
            } else {
                sMsg = "Return Code: " + m[1] + "\n" + m[2] + "(Upload Error)";
            }

            MessageToast.show(sMsg);
        }
    },

    handleUploadPress: function(oEvent) {
        var oFileUploader = this.getView().byId("fileUploader");
        oFileUploader.upload();
    }
});

return ControllerController;

});
```

When I run this in the debugger I get an Uncaught TypeError:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
at f.handleUploadComplete (FileUploader.controller.js?eval:11)
at f.a.fireEvent (EventProvider-dbg.js:229)
at f.a.fireEvent (Element-dbg.js:427)
at f.fireUploadComplete (ManagedObjectMetadata-dbg.js:426)
at HTMLIFrameElement.eval (FileUploader.js?eval:6)
at HTMLIFrameElement.dispatch (jquery-dbg.js:4737)
at HTMLIFrameElement.c3.handle (jquery-dbg.js:4549)

 if (m[1] == "200") {
                sMsg = "Return Code: " + m[1] + "\n" + m[2] + "(Upload Success)";
                oEvent.getSource().setValue("");
```

I searched for sample code and it seems my code is ok, but I don't know why I can't upload a file by click on the button.

Comment: No one wants to debug your code for you. Have you tried debugging this? Every browser has a JS console these days, and all you have to do is start with some print debugging.

Comment: Yes i debug this code.  there is an uncaught typeError.

Comment: I've moved the exception details to the body of the question for you by _editing_ the question. Comments are for clarification, and answers are for, well, answers.Please review [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [did you take the tour?](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: You need to start debugging, as I don't think anyone can help you with this because it is specific to your environment. It looks like "m" is null, so getting the "1" property out of it fails. That's my naive understanding. You should verify that whatever "m" is, it is non-null if you want to get a property out of it. My guess is you are getting a null response from the response, or your regular expression is evaluating to null. Work from the known to the unknown to find the bug. Step 1: are you getting anything back as a response? Is the server even being reached?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem ! :) 
So, instead of using this

```
var m = /^[(\d\d\d)]:(.)$/.exec(sResponse);
```

use this in view FileUploader :

```
sendXHR="true"
```

After, on controller js you can use for status :

```
oEvent.getParameter("status")
```

and for getting answer as a json file :

```
 var jsonfile = JSON.parse(oEvent.getParameter("responseRaw"));
```

Then access your sent object attributes from server (only when use dataType: 'json')

```
jsonfile.attribute
```

I hope this helps a lot!